# Java memory usage and object not eligible for gc

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I have a problem of memory usage in my application, it start some task that full the memory. I expect that, when the task finish, the gc will clean the memory, but it never happen.
I wish to say that the code is witten very bad (like my English :(   ). This makes some extraction from db and it make a massive usage of variables, store they in lists and at the end write all values to a file.
First of all I tried to write values to file frequently, but nothing change. I read that an object became eligible for the gc only if it has no reference to nothing, so, it is possible to see (maybe in debug) the tree reference of an object? In this way i can nullify the parent object at the end of the task. I know that the solution is to re-write the code, but it is very complex and we don't have much effort to do that, so we need a temporary solution.

Thank you

Bye

Comment: Need to see some code. You have the basic idea of GC correct, but are you implementing your code to allow for GC to do its job?

Comment: `I know that the solution is to re-write the code, but it is very complex and we don't have much effort to do that, so we need a temporary solution.` This "temporary" solution will very likely become a permanent solution. I suggest rewriting now to spare headaches later.

Comment: Try to run some static code analysis using tools like Lint4j or equivalent and set warning level high. You could be pointed to code parts missing resource liberation like not closing streams and file handles, and fix them quickly without changing the whole code.

Comment: Also, to monitor resource usage and garbage collection behavior for your java application you can start it with jmx options so you can connect jmx console and have a detailed view on how it is consuming memory

Comment: “*I expect that, when the task finish, the gc will clean the memory*”—Why do you expect that? The garbage collector has no notion of “finished tasks”; the garbage collector will run when there’s not enough memory to satisfy a new allocation request. Before that, it just let the JVM fill the memory. The memory is there to be used and garbage collection requires CPU time, so it won’t waste it. Since you didn’t say that you got `OutOfMemoryError`s or performance problems, it’s possible that you don’t have a problem at all.